# Desktop Icons Off Screen Combined Display Ubuntu 14.10 Gnome 13.14

Tags: gnome, ati, multiple-monitors, 14.10

I have two monitors side by side both with the same 1680x1050 resolution, but one is lower than the other. But if I arrange them as such in the display settings then any icons that I have at the top will appear offscreen or if I arrange the icons on the screen they will go offscreen.

This happens in both gnome 13.12 and 13.14.

Additionally in gnome 13.14 some programs will get graphical glitches if maximized on the lower monitor. Either where things are out of place or where buttons appear selected either below or above the actual button.

I'm also using the proprietary fglrx-updates driver for my Radeon HD 7850, but at least in 13.12 it had the same icon problem with the x.org driver. Haven't tried using the x.org driver in 13.14 yet.

Any thoughts?

I have considered going back to gnome 13.12 but I updated to 13.14 because I was unable to get spanning wallpapers or separate wallpapers per display to work in 13.12. In 13.14 I've at least been able to get spanning wallpapers to work.

EDIT:
The graphical glitches disappeared in 13.14, so that's no longer an issue. Also my problem is the same as the one in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465627/desktop-icons-off-screen) question.